# 20 years on, they have done OR did it again?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I am not sure that I heard the CNN reporter (American Speaker) well when he was talking about the winner of the world cup 2018, He said: 20 years on, they have done it again. Isn't it more appropriate to use the simple past here, "20 years on, they did it again" because we know when France won the first and the second Worldcups?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both are idiomatic, but **have done** is in light of the fact that the second win is in the present year. *Now*, they have done it again.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct but the present perfect from (have done) is more appropriate in this case.

I assume the context is a description of the immediate and ongoing consequences of the win (celebrations, player careers etc.) so the present tense is more correct.